# Handling large amount of data -Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

The Web API we created queries the OracleDB and returns a huge set of records and we will have to convert it in to the JSON

Below is the actual Controller code

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] id)
{
 string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    var inconditions = id.Distinct().ToArray();
    var srtcon = string.Join(",", inconditions);
    DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
    var strQuery = @"SELECT * from STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY where STPR_STUDY.STD_REF IN(" + srtcon + ")";
    using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand(strQuery, dbconn))
    {
        using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(selectCommand))
        {
            DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(selectResults);
            var returnObject = new { data = selectResults };
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
            if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
            {
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
            }
            return response;
```

The issue is if we have huge number of rows like 300,000 it throws Out of memory exception. I read in other forums that this issue can be solved by pagination. But I am looking to get entire set of records at once, as the client application requires entire result when the Web API is called. I am not sure how would I handle this. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how much is your RAM capacity?

Comment: This application runs on a Windows server 2012

Comment: Windows server 2012 is an Operation System. RAM is random access memory. These are 2 different things. the Application gives you Memory exception. I want to know how much is your memory capacity???

Comment: Sorry I missed typing the RAM size its 8GB

Comment: @MRebati This application runs on a Windows server 2012 and RAM size 8GB

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732365/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown-web-api

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by adding some parameters to my *web.config*:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
```

(this is placed inside `<system.webServer><security><requestFiltering>`)

and

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="1600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
```

(this has to be in the section `<system.web>`)

Comment: Thanks Robert, the tags <security><requestFiltering> Was not present in the web.config. I added them manually. I tried to run the application again, it keeps loading for long time. Is there any chance of improving the time to return the result little faster.

Comment: it took forever to lad and again it is throwing the out of memory exception

Comment: the id I tested should return 633060 rows.. But throws this error.. I did add breakpoint in the application it didn't show any error on the code

Comment: If you run into a memory shortage, the given steps won't help you, unfortunately. You need to implement pagination, lazy loading or something similar.